# How to generate information from telegram using a Python based Telegram bot and it’s API like it’s done with GetUpdate in addressbars in web browsers

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Hi everyone so I’m new to developing bots for Telegram with Python and I need help being able to generate the basic get updates information. I usually can when I use the web browser, you know when you drop the telegram link with the bot token key and finish it up with the GetUpdate function in the address bar then the browser just generates a page with all the info such as chat_id, user_id, firstname,last name, etc. Yeah I want to know how to do that with Python so I can achieve the same results in the python terminal. I’m working with the telegram bot for python package so I think it’s called telegram.ext. I’m using the basic guide which involves me using the Dispatcher and Updater, I’m still learning from the guide but for now I need to know how to get that system/session info using my bot in the python terminal. Feel free to ask any questions to clarify this question, thanks.

So far I the most I can do is print out messages I’ve sent to the bot but that’s about it, it’s  pretty much filtered and I don’t want that I want the raw and unorganized information like browser usually provides.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `requests` [library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT_TOKEN>/getupdates')
print(r.json())
```

Comment: I receive an error that says “No module named requests”

Comment: Because you have to install `requests` lib